# Local apt mirror just for a single release

Tags: apt

With the instructions at https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors one can create an apt mirror of raspbian. 
This clones the whole repo of packages belonging to all the releases of Raspbian i.e. Wheezy & Jessie. 
I am interested in mirroring just the **main** repo of **Jessie**.

How should I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

**Fast way** (dirty)

Create a file (let's name it `exclude.txt`) in wich you will list pathes to be ignored by rsync (ex: `raspbian/dists/wheezy/`), then add the parameter `--exclude-from=exclude.txt`

It is not clean because it will save disk space, but won't correct the indexes of the DB.

**Clean way** (slower)

Install and configure [apt-mirror](https://apt-mirror.github.io). It will maintain a local DB, based on the real content that you had choosen. But it's configuration is out of scope, here.

Answer (score 0):

Install **apt-mirror** and configure the archive `/etc/apt/mirror.list`
Add this lines with just main:

```
deb-armhf http_mirror_address jessie main
```

add this line in cleaning section

```
clean http_mirror_address
```

And that's it